# How to exclude long hash in serveless logs

Tags: node.js, logging, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

Currently, I am using serverless + express. What I did for logging is using `serverless logs -f server -t --stage dev`. but, I got a very long string generated by serverless like this:

[image: serverless log]

My question is, how to remove all those long strings and outputs only console logs (or any other logger)?

Those long random strings are useless in logging.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found a command that removes the function id/hash. According to above's question, this command works:

```sh
serverless logs -f <HANDLER> -t --stage <STAGE> --filter <KEYWORD>
```

example:

```sh
serverless logs -f server -t --stage dev --filter "-SERVERLESS_ENTERPRISE"
```

*ps.
I am open to new answer or a better way to filter only logs that are written on purpose. This is just a workaround as it filters based on certain keyword.*